# Condition Coverage and Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit, separation-of-concerns, test-coverage

when writing unit tests (with junit), is it necessary to separate test methods to reach a complete condition coverage?

take this snippet for example:

```
int foo(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c){
    if(a && b && c)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Is it better to write one method and different assertions for condition coverage if this if? Or one method for each condition?

```
@Test
void conditionsTest(){
    assertEqual(0, foo(true, false, false));
    assertEqual(0, foo(true, true, false));
    assertEqual(1, foo(true, true, true));
    ...
}
```

**OR**

```
@Test
void condition1Test(){
    assertEqual(0, foo(true, false, false));
}

@Test
void condition2Test(){
    assertEqual(0, foo(true, true, false));
}

@Test
void condition3Test(){
    assertEqual(1, foo(true, true, true));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not *necessary* to split the tests it can be *better* to do so:

1. The all-in-one test function will abort execution on the first failed assertion. No information on the other combinations. When separated you will have more detailed information on which combinations fail exactly. Note that [parameterized tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) will achieve the same.
2. From a coverage point of view the all-in-one test will amass the coverage in a single test. With no way to analyze the contribution of each combination of conditions. This becomes even more valuable when going for more complex condition coverage metrics like [MC/DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage).

Granted: the second aspect depends on the granularity of data collection provided by your coverage tool. Our company's tool [Coco](https://www.froglogic.com/coco/) collects coverage per test function but does so for C, C++ and C# only so far. You may want to look for the equivalent capability for Java code.